# exceptions .IDE netbeans build failed

Tags: java

hello on netbeans i take this message:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Your
>   number is false  at erg5.Erg5.main(Erg5.java:128) 
>   C:\Users\ekte\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53:
>   Java returned: 1  BUILD FAILED (total time: 15 seconds)

I did the exception but is wrong ? it shouldnt say build failed?
code :

```
public class Erg5 {

      public static void main(String[] args)  {

         int lkR;
         int mer=90;
         lkR= Vehicle.lRe();//it is a method and i save a number from the class Vehicle 
         if(lkR<0 || lkR>meR){

              throw new IllegalArgumentException("Your number is false"); 

          }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Build Failed" just means that your program threw an exception, and exited abnormally (as throwing an exception often does).

Comment: Not at all. AFAIK, Netbeans just says that whenever your main method did not complete.